# Поиск дубликатов

Tags: mysql, sql

Я пытаюсь выбрать дубликаты записей из mysql, суть в следующем:
Есть таблица с данными, основные `ip`, `auth`. Нужно найти все записи где при одинаковом `ip` разные `auth`.
Спасибо :)

Comment: А ну, марш RTFM )

Comment: @AlexanderChernin зачем так грубо?) На первый взгляд вопрос легкий, но видимо не на столько

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так вы выберете все ип, где 2+ уникальных auth

```
select ip,
       count(distinct auth) as "q_unique_auth"
  from my_table
 group by ip
having count(distinct auth) > 1
;
```

Вставить данные во временную таблицу и после join с этой же таблицей my_table по ip

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ip
  FROM sometable
 GROUP BY ip
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT auth) > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select count(auth), ip from table group by ip
```

Comment: Это показывает кол-во всех auth для одного ip, но не учитывает что они все одинаковые. Я же ищу вариант, при котором выборка только уникальных)